# Registering Vue components in html files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm having trouble using Vue.js components in HTML files.
Mainly I have a problem with registering the component and using it in the html file.
In general, I'd like to register a component and use it anywhere in the code. The current code that I took from the original Vue.js website works so that the component is added to the application right away.

index.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <header></header>
        <nav></nav>
        <main></main>
        <footer> </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from 'vue'
  import MyComponent from './header.js'

  createApp(MyComponent).mount('#app')
</script>
```

Header.js:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return { count: 0 }
  },
  template: `<div>count is {{ count }}</div>`
}
```

Then the created component in another file actually works, but it is added automatically to the application.
How could I register this component and put it in the code where I want?

Comment: iirc `app =  createApp(...); app.component('MyComp2', MyComp2)`

Comment: @Dimava that's my suggestion too, register the component globally

Comment: @iirc Im new to Vue.js, Can you explain how Can I implement this into my code or provide me with example?